# What is a $p$-adic group

Tags: abstract-algebra, p-adic-number-theory, algebraic-groups

I saw the name $p$-adic group on a book I was reading, so I tried to find some related documents. Although I've found something on this topic, there is no definition.

Would anyone please explain the definition for a $p$-adic group to me? Thanks very much.

Comment: Intuitively, it's integers base $p$, with infinite number of digits allowed.

Comment: I'd say that @Arthur 's comment is an explanation of $p$-adic integers, but, to me, a $p$-adic _group_ is the $p$-adic points of an algebraic group, like $GL_2({\mathbb Q}_p)$. Intuitively, groups of matrices with $p$-adic entries. I hope the OP will give some context as to which definition is meant.

Comment: First, look up p-adic numbers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since the only tag you put is group-theory, it may be the case that you do not have the appropriate background for understanding the following definition. Nonetheless, here is an attempt.

First, let $\mathbb{Q}_p$ be the field of $p$-adic numbers, and let $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p$ be an algebraic closure. Let $G=Gal(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p/\mathbb{Q}_p)$. If you look at the field $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ itself, you can see that it is the solution set of the zero polynomial, and that the zero polynomial is the only polynomial to vanish identically on $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p$. We say that $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p$ is an *algebraic group*, associated to the *affine variety* corresponding to the vanishing set of the zero polynomial. The algebraic group $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is now the set of fixed points (we call them the $\mathbb{Q}_p$-rational points) for the Galois action of $G$ on $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p$. Note that this is well defined because the zero polynomial is *defined over $\mathbb{Q}_p$*, that is, its coefficients lie in $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Another example is $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p^\times$. This can be identified with the vanishing set for the polynomial $XY-1$ in $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p^2$. Again, since $XY-1$ is defined over $\mathbb{Q}_p$, we can see the algebraic group $\mathbb{Q}_p^\times$ as the set of fixed points for the action of $G$ on $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p^\times$.

Now, more generally, what you need is an affine variety $X$ over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p$ with a group structure on it which is given by polynomial equations. More precisely, both multiplication and inversion are to be given by polynomial equations. This is an *algebraic group*. It will be given as the vanishing set of a collection of polynomials. If these polynomials can be chosen over $\mathbb{Q}_p$, as well as the polynomials giving multiplication and inversion, then you have an action of $G$ on $X$, and the fixed points will form an algebraic group over $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Therefore, here is the definition:

A $p$-adic group is an algebraic group over a $p$-adic field, or more precisely, it is the $\mathbb{Q}_p$-rational points of an algebraic group over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p$.

---

The above is a definition. Here is a very important result:

> **Theorem**: Every (affine) algebraic group is linear, that is, it can realised as a subgroup of a matrix group.

Hence, every $p$-adic group is a group of matrix with entries in the field $\mathbb{Q}_p$ of $p$-adic numbers.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. In fact I knew about algebraic groups, but I didn't know the relation between $p$-adic groups and algebraic groups before I read your answer. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 5):

The following is **not a perfect** description of a $p$-adic group, but hopefully it will help a bit.

Let $F$ be a [non-Archimedean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_numbers) [local field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_field): That is you have a [valuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_valuation) $v: F \to \mathbb{Z}\cup \{\infty\}$ which satisfies that $v\lvert_{F^{\times}}: F^{\times} \to \mathbb{Z}$ is a homomorphism. You have a subring of integers $\mathcal{O}$ of $F$ which is defined by $\mathcal{O} = \{r \in F\lvert v(f) \geq 0\}$. You have a unique maximal ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ in $\mathcal{O}$: $\mathfrak{p} = \{r \in \mathcal{O} \lvert v(r) > 0\}$. We have $\mathcal{O} / \mathfrak{p}$ is a field; assume that it is finite or order $q$.

A $p$-adic group is a group over such a field. You can think of for example $GL_n(F)$.

As something a bit more concrete, you can take $\mathbb{Q}$. Here you have a valuation $v$ defined by $v\left(\frac{a}{b}\right) = v(a) - v(b)$, where if for $a\in \mathbb{Q}$ $a = p^nc$, ($p \nmid c$) $v(a) = n$. The completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ with respect to the norm $\lvert x\lvert = \left(\frac{1}{q}\right)^{v(x)}$ is called $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Note: There are other ways to see this and there are probably people who are going to disagree with the outline of the definition that I have given, but maybe it will be helpful anyway just to illustrate some of the things there are hiding in the background when talking about $p$-adic groups.

Comment: I think the most difficult part of understanding the definition of a $p$-adic group, is understanding the definition of an algebraic group over a field, which is left out of your answer. But at least, we are now certain that the OP will have seen a proper definition of $p$-adic numbers

Comment: @MTurgeon: I agree completely. To be honest, I still struggle with understanding algebraic groups. Excellent that you added your answer to address this.

Comment: Fair enough. I still gave you +1 for your definition of $p$-adic numbers, which I think we can assume will be useful for the OP. And to be fair, you did put a disclaimer at the beginning of your question.